# Proving that $\sin(nx) = \sum_{j=0}^{[n/2]} (-1)^j {n \choose 2j}(\cos(x))^{n-2j}(\sin(x))^{2j}$ with induction

Tags: trigonometry

We have to prove:
$$ \sin(nx) = \sum_{j=0}^{[n/2]} (-1)^j {n \choose 2j}(\cos(x))^{n-2j}(\sin(x))^{2j}$ with induction $$
where $[n/2]$ stand for the floor function of $n/2$.
I know this formula can be proven with other methods but I want to prove it using the formula:
$$ \cos⁡(nx)=2 \cos⁡(x)  \cos⁡((n-1)x)-\cos⁡((n-2)x) $$
so I've already done the first 2 cases for $n=1,2$ and now I assume that $n$ is odd, and I use $ \cos⁡(nx)=2 \cos⁡(x)  \cos⁡((n-1)x)-\cos⁡((n-2)x) $ and I write $\cos⁡((n-1)x)$ and $\cos⁡((n-2)x)$ as sums using the induction hypothesis, and then I have to put the right terms together so I get some nice cancellation but for some reason I can't find the right way to pair them up.

Comment: Are we talking about even $n$ or is $[n/2]$ the floor $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$?
Also I'd suggest formulating the question also in the body - the title is no replacement for the first line of its body.

Comment: I edited my question.